# How to retrieve JSON Response from a javax.ws.rs.core.Response response?

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, jax-rs, webclient

I am making a request to an API and getting a response status code of `200`.

Response of the api includes a `json` response.

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

Response response = webclient.post(SomeReqString);
```

How can I retrieve the `json` response as string from the web client response?

Answer (score 69):

You can use following code

```
String responseAsString = response.readEntity(String.class);
```

Comment: I tried this. The `response` object doesn't have a method called `readEntity()`

Comment: I don't know if it is deprecated by now. It at least had it once. https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html#readEntity-java.lang.Class-

Answer (score 11):

Try using the [`Response.getEntity()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html#getEntity%28%29) method, which returns an [InputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html?is-external=true). Then, to convert your InputStream to a String, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/read-convert-an-inputstream-to-a-string). If you really need to map the JSON String to a Java entity, that consider calling directly the [`Response.readEntity()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html#readEntity%28java.lang.Class%29). Note that, if you consume the InputStream, you will probably have to process the input stream on your own.

Comment: For me the getEntity() method is always returning null. I had to use readEntity(). (javax.ws.rs.core.Response from JavaEE 7).

Answer (score -3):

You could try

```
String responseAsString = response.getEntity().toString();
```

Comment: This just leads to output like `org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector$2@50612c54`