# Correct way to consume json stream result in java?

Tags: neo4j

In the Neo4j manual, in the section about [unmanaged extensions](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-unmanaged-extensions.html) can be read:

> Neo4j’s Transactional Cypher HTTP endpoint (see Section 21.1, “Transactional Cypher HTTP endpoint”) streams responses back to the client and we should follow in its footsteps.

So that's exactly what I do BUT: What's the correct way to consume the response?
Right now I just do:

`Response.readEntity(String.class)`

But I think that I'm not taking advantage of the streaming, I'm just consuming the entire result. Is there a better way to do this, or is the streaming just server side and I shouldn't worry about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wanted to share my discoveries:

`Response` has a `getEntity()` that returns an `InputStream` then you have to process that `Stream` by yourself. [This is the question that helped me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25196427/how-to-retrieve-json-response-from-a-javax-ws-rs-core-response-response)