# Why my REST application returns some weird response?

Tags: java, rest

I'm starting with REST, and I want to write simple app where you write movie title, and it takes from web server (in my example [The Movie DB](https://www.themoviedb.org/?language=en-US)) information about all movies that matches that title (e.g. if I write "Harry Potter" I should get "Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone", "Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets" ...).

I'm completly new to the topic, but I wrote some code to write the title, but I have the problem with the part where I ask server. So I wrote simplest code, where I have ready to use URI in getURI_1 method:

```
(...)
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public void newForm(@FormParam("movie title") String movie_title,
                    @Context HttpServletResponse servletResponse) throws IOException {

Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget target = client.target(getURI_1());
Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, MY_KEY_HERE);

Response response = invocationBuilder.get();
String output = response.getEntity().toString();

System.out.println(output);
}

(...)
```

and:

```
private  static URI getURI_1() {
        return UriBuilder.fromUri("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=MY_KEY_HERE&query=Harry+Potter").build();
    }
```

My problem is as a result I ges something like this:

```
org.glassfish.jersey.client.HttpUrlConnector$2@4c4d97af
```

Can somebody tell me what is this?

Comment: is that answer helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25200868/2516301 ?

Comment: @vefthym Yes,that's what I'm looking for, thanks a lot